# Routing with NODE.JS . The "/" route is found but the other routes are not found

Tags: javascript, node.js, express

Hi have a shared hosting that supports node js and I uploaded my code there and when I hit my domain I get the home directory (the "/" directory). Now when I click on the anchor tag on that page it does not take me to the new routes."404 - File or directory not found". I dont know what is happening there. Can any one help me?

my app.js

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();

app.use(express.static("public"));
app.set("view engine", "ejs");

app.get("/hei", function(req, res) {
    res.render("hello2");
});

app.get("/", function(req, res) {
    res.render("hello");
});



//app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);
//the port and the Ip address
app.listen(process.env.PORT, "My IP", function() {
    console.log("server done");
});
```

my hello.ejs

```
<h1> Hi tehre Brother </h1>

<a href="/hei"> Go Back hei</a>
```

my hello2.ejs

```
<h1> Hola </h1>

<a href="/"> Go Back hello</a>
```

Comment: Does this work locally?

Comment: yes it works perfectly

Comment: can you see any logs on the other end at all? or can you check the logs and  verify if the request to access `/hei` route had correct path .. `GET http://domain/route_name - 404` ...etc

Comment: My confusion is its a shared hosting. I used the app in vps and everything is working fine. I think when I hit the "/" the app listens to the port but when I move to route /hei the server stops listeneing. I dont know waht is happening. When I click on the anchor tag i get the right link like "GET http://domain/hei" but I get 404 @Alexus

Comment: What is the port number? Also, you are getting the 404 page from express or from the default server from server?

Comment: getting it from the server not the express. The port number is taken from the environment variable.@nightgauunt